# How is distance between two points defined in barycentric coordinates?

Tags: geometry, simplex

Hope someone can help. 
I have this 3-d simplex (a tetrahedron) and its vertexes have barycentric coordinates defined as follow: $A_1=(1,0,0,0), A_2=(0,1,0,0), A_3=(0,0,1,0), A_4=(0,0,0,1)$. I am wondering what is the distance between, for example, $A_1$ and $A_2$? I know that an any point T on the edge $\bar{A_1A_2}$ is determined by a number t $\in$ [0,1] such that $\frac{t}{1-t}=\frac{\bar{A_2T}}{\bar{TA_1}}$ and its barycentric coordinates thus are (t,1-t,0,0). I intuitively understand it, but why is it like this? Thank you in advance

Comment: At least in the usual sense, the distance between two points given in barycentric coordinates is not defined at all. Barycentric coordinates are invariant under affine transformations which transform the simplex along with the coordinate system, but distances change under these transformations.